# Is there a way to convert ipynb code to webapp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to convert the following jupyter python code to webapp.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interactive

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100) # 100 points from 0 to 2pi

def plotter(A, B):
    y = A*np.sin(B*x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.grid()
    plt.ylim(-3,3)
    plt.show()

interactive(plotter, A=(-3, 3, 0.1), B=(1, 5, 0.5))
```

I am a complete beginner and would like to know if its even possible to do that. If not, what would be the best way to go forward to achieving the same output in a webapp. Because I use matplotlib extensively, it'd be a great help if I could somehow incorporate matplotlib, ipywidgets into my webapp.

Comment: Depending on what you actually want to achieve, running the notebook in Binder (https://mybinder.org/) might be an option to look into.

Comment: Yes, following on @mad's suggestion. You can use [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) with MyBinder.  There's lots of examples at [the Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/). I have some example of my own [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila). ipywidgets and Voila work great together. There's also [appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) that works with MyBinder. See [this thread on the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-transform-a-jupyter-notebook-into-a-webapp/758?u=fomightez) for a related discussion.

Comment: The example you included may be doable now as static code without a backing Python kernel via pyodide because matplotlib & numpy already work there, see [Embedding Jupyter everywhere](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-everywhere-f8151c2cc6e8). ipywidgets work according to [here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/326) & [here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/discussions/236). I saw a demo [here](https://jupyterlite.github.io/demo/retro/notebooks/?path=pyolite%20kernel%20examples%20/interactive-widgets.ipynb), but not quite sure how easy to make a site using them yet.

Comment: Thank you all. Voila does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to convert Jupyter Notebook into a web app:

1. You can use [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila). It spins for you a Tornado server. You need to use ipywidgets to make a notebook interactive.
2. You can use [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury). The widgets for the notebook are added based on the YAML header. It has many unique features like:

- exporting executed notebook to PDF,
- hiding the code,
- sharing multiple notebooks,
- scheduling of the notebook,
- adding authentication to notebook ([commercial feature](https://mljar.com/mercury/))

Here is an example of a Jupyter Notebook converted to a web app with Mercury:

#### Notebook

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

#### Notebook with YAML header

[image: Jupyter Notebook with YAML header]

#### Web App from Notebook built with Mercury

[image]